# Converting a relative path to absolute on Mac and Linux

Tags: c++, linux, macos, relative-path, filepath

This is what I'm trying to implement:

```
CString r = CDir("/users/administrator/path/3/4/5").absolutePathFor("../../2/../3/");
```

`r` should now contain "/users/administrator/path/3/3/".

On Windows this is done with `GetFullPathName`. On Linux and Mac there's plain old C function `realpath()` that almost does the trick. However, it has one huge issue: it seems to only work with paths that actually exist. In my example some part of the path doesn't exist, and that part is truncated from the result returned by `realpath`. What other functions are available on Mac and Linux that can solve my task?

Comment: Have you considered using Boost? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

Comment: @wojciii: Boost is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want to compute what the path would be even if the path doesn't exist (so you can't ask the OS about it)?

In this case I guess you can make a function that would take the current directory parameter and the relative path as arguments. You then check what you have between every /. If it's "." you ignore it, if it's ".." you remove the last directory from the current path, if it's something else you add it to the current path.

A good way to implement it would be to use a stack for the path (you push/pop) and a queue for the relative path. Converting the string to this should be pretty easy. Like for example (for making the base path)

I assume BasePath is the input string parameter for the path

```
std::stack<string>path;
string temp;
for (int i=0;i<BasePath.size()
    if(BasePath[i]!='/')
        temp+=BasePath[i];
    else
        path.push(temp), temp.clear();
```

This is pretty ugly and could be done with regular expressions but since you said you don't have Boost I'll also assume you don't have C++11 and for this complexity you can get away without it anyway.

For the interesting part you can do it like that

```
while(!relativepath.empty())
{
    if(relativepath.front()==".."
        path.pop();
    if(relativepath.front()=="." {}
    else
        path.push(relativepath.front());
   relativepath.pop();
}
```

I'm not sure it's what you wanted but it's not so hard to make and you can easily adapt for Windows/Linux by changing the separator.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. It's weird that there's no system API function for it, though. As I said, on Windows there is a WinAPI function `GetFullPathName` that does this.

Comment: I ended up combining both approaches: call `realpath` first (if the OS can do the job - let it, it'll do it more reliably), and if that fails, resolve the `.` and `..` symbols manually using a stack, as described in this answer.